# Scraping the data out of the text

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, text, steamworks-api, steambot

I am working on a price checker app for steamcommunity market. I have used the following code to extract the source-code out of the website, which includes all of the sales that has been made untill today. Can you please help me to get the data, which is between "[[]]" signs?

```
import requests
sites = [
    "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"
]
for url in sites:
    r = requests.get(url)
    page_source = r.text
    page_source = page_source.split('\n')
    print("\nURL:", url) 
    
    for row in page_source[:]:
        print(row)
```

Comment: can you clarify what you are looking for exact? what do you want your code to output, and what is it currently doing?

Comment: In the source code there is a python list that indicates the sales has has been made since 2014. I want to get the data and try to find an average price for the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used  regex  to extract the data

```
import requests
import re
import json

sites = [
    "https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29"
]
for url in sites:
    r = requests.get(url)
    page_source = r.text
    # print(page_source)
    results = re.search(r'var line1=\[.*\]',page_source).group()
    print(results[10:])
```